# Interpolate a single row of a table

Tags: r, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a row of a data frame at a single point.  I can use `approx` to get a single value, but need to end up with a vector or single line with one value for each column of the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4),
  y1 = c(-.6,-.4, .4, 1.2),
  y2 = c(-.7, -.4, .4, .46),
  y3 = c(-.8, -.3, .5, 1.2)
)
df
    x   y1    y2   y3
1 1.1 -0.6 -0.70 -0.8
2 1.2 -0.4 -0.40 -0.3
3 1.3  0.4  0.40  0.5
4 1.4  1.2  0.46  1.2

target_x <- 1.24

## Works
approx(df$x, df$y1, target_x)$y
>[1] -0.08

### looking for something like approx(df$x, df[,2:4], target_x)
## should return:
> [1] -0.08 -0.08  0.02
```

Linear interpolation is fine, I do not need to extrapolate beyond the existing table.  Either base R or dplyr approaches are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
sapply(df[, 2:4], \(y) approx(x=df$x, y=y, xout=target_x)$y)
#    y1    y2    y3 
# -0.08 -0.08  0.02
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4), y1 = c(-0.6, -0.4, 
0.4, 1.2), y2 = c(-0.7, -0.4, 0.4, 0.46), y3 = c(-0.8, -0.3, 
0.5, 1.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

target_x <- 1.24
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `dplyr` using `reframe()` with `across()` to identify all the variables that start with "y".  Here's what it would look like.  In the `across()` statement below, the `.x` stands in for each of the variables in the across statement - in this case, all of the variables that start with "y".

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4),
  y1 = c(-.6,-.4, .4, 1.2),
  y2 = c(-.7, -.4, .4, .46),
  y3 = c(-.8, -.3, .5, 1.2)
)

target_x <- 1.24

df %>% 
  reframe(across(starts_with("y"), 
                 ~approx(x, .x, target_x)$y))
#>      y1    y2   y3
#> 1 -0.08 -0.08 0.02
```

There is also a base R option using `sapply()` where the first argument is the list of variable names you want to use as the y-variable in `approx` as a vector of character strings.

```r
sapply(c("y1", "y2", "y3"), function(y){
  approx(df$x, df[[y]], target_x)$y
})
#>    y1    y2    y3 
#> -0.08 -0.08  0.02
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Which one you use may depend on what kind of output you want.  The `dplyr` solution returns a data frame whereas the `sapply()` solution returns a named numeric vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can `Vectorize` the function `approx`, e.g.,

```
> with(df, Vectorize(approx, "y")(x, list(y1, y2, y3), 1.24))
  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
x 1.24  1.24  1.24
y -0.08 -0.08 0.02
```